# How do I use multi threading in TCL?

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to run two procedures in parallel. As TCL is the interpreter, it will process procedures one by one. Can someone explain with an example how I can use multi-threading in TCL?

Comment: This question asks for [this obligatory reference](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 9):

These days, the usual way to do multi-threading in Tcl is to use its [`Thread` extension](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/thread) — it's being developed along with the Tcl's core, but on certain platforms (such as various Linux-based OSes) you might need to install a separate package to get this extension available.

[The threading model](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/thread_model.html) the `Thread` extension implements is "one thread per interpreter".  This means, each thread can "host" just one Tcl interpreter (and an unlimited number of its child interpreters), but no code executed by any thread may access interpreters hosted in other threads.  This, in turn, means that when you work with threads in Tcl, you have to master the idea of multiple interpreters.

The classical approach to exchanging data between interpreters running in different threads is *message passing:* you post *scripts* to the *input queue* of the target interpreter running in different thread and then wait for reply.  On the other hand, thread-shared variables (implementing sharing memory by locking) is also available.  Another available feature is support for thread pools.

Read the ["Tcl and threads"](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+and+threads) wiki page, the [`Thread`'s extension manual pages](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/thread.htm).

The code examples are on the wiki.  Here's just [one of them](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Sharing+a+common+logger+thread+example).

Please note that if your procedures which, you think, have to be run in parrallel, *are mostly I/O bound* (that is, they read something from the network and/or send something there) and not *CPU-bound* (doing heavy computations), you might have better results with the event-based approach to processing: the Tcl has built-in support for the event loop, and you are able to make Tcl execute your code when the next chunk of data can be read from a channel (such as a network socket) or written to a channel.

Comment: Wow, such an archaic-looking language and it has a multithreaded interpreter! :-) With it, it overwhelms php, perl5, ruby and python. :-)

Comment: @peterh, being curly-bracey makes a language look only some 10 years less archaic: BCPL is from 1966 while LISP (which Tcl resembles by having essentially no syntax and nested braces) is from 1958 (see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/188463) for more). But we digress...

Comment: @kostix And do they have multithreaded interpreter (with OS-level threads!), with multithreaded graph-walking garbage collector? Yes, I know it is hard to develop, but I think it should be a minimal criteria for any globally used interpreted language. Surprisingly, none of the today used, popular languages have this feature, except java (and c#). I find this shocking. If tcl can do this, I will love tcl. If tcl has this, I interpret it as the perfection of the nice oldies.

Comment: @peterh [Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) has parallel GC w/o STW phases and is as simple to write and read as any "contemporary" scripting language. May I recommend studying it more? ;-)

Comment: @kostix Yes. On the first spot, its syntax and its class model makes me crying, but after I've accustomed it a little bit more, it may later enjoy me. :-)