# how to pass blt vectors in a separate thread

Tags: c, multithreading, tcl

I have this function call to a database, I'm using C and tcl/tk so tcl calls of this function that gets executed in C, but while that is happening the system in tcl hangs for the time it process the query call and the time it fills the vectors, I want the tcl application to continue working and have this process in a separate thread. This is what i'm trying right now.

C function that process the database call and fills the vectors:

```
static int getEpochPrototype(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[]){
    Tcl_Obj *result;
    char sampleid[15];
    char tclxVec[15];
    char tclyVec[15];
    int length;
    int numResults;
    int i;
    Blt_Vector *xCVec, *yCVec;

    if (objc != 4) {
        Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 3, objv, "number of argument error");
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    strcpy(sampleid,Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[1], &length));
    strcpy(tclxVec,Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[2], &length));
    strcpy(tclyVec,Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[3], &length));

    if (Blt_VectorExists(interp, tclxVec) != TCL_OK || Blt_VectorExists(interp, tclyVec) != TCL_OK) {
        if ((Blt_GetVector(interp, tclxVec, &xCVec) != TCL_OK) || (Blt_GetVector(interp, tclyVec, &yCVec) != TCL_OK)) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }
    } else {
           printf("Vector not found \n");
           return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    char command[256];
    PQclear(res);

    strcpy(command, "select extract ('epoch' from \"Timestamp\"), \"BioAccumulated\" from \"Results\" where \"SampleID\" = '");
    strcat(command, sampleid);
    strcat(command, "' order by \"Timestamp\" asc");
    res = PQexec(conn,command);
    numResults = PQntuples(res);
    double x[numResults], y[numResults];

    for (i = 0; i < numResults; i++)
    {   
        x[i] = strtod(PQgetvalue(res,i,0), NULL);
        y[i] = strtod(PQgetvalue(res,i,1), NULL);

    }

    /* Put the data into BLT vectors */
    if ((Blt_ResetVector(xCVec, x, numResults, numResults, TCL_VOLATILE) != TCL_OK) || (Blt_ResetVector(yCVec, y, numResults, numResults, TCL_VOLATILE) != TCL_OK)) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }


   return TCL_OK;
}
```

TCL Function trying to send the blt vectors to the c thread:

```
blt::vector create xVec
blt::vector create yVec

tsv::set graph xtemp_shared xVec
tsv::set graph yBio_shared yVec

thread::create {
    load ./samples.so
    connectDB2

    #puts  "[tsv::get details sampleid_shared]"
    getEpochPrototype [tsv::get details sampleid_shared] [tsv::get graph xtemp_shared] [tsv::get graph yBio_shared]
}
```

When I try this I get the "vector not found", which is the print statement that I put when the vectors cant be found or there is an error, is there another way to do it or am i missing something ?

Comment: `tsv::set` is a syntax error in C. Did you mean C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

Tcl's [threading model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442131/how-do-i-use-multi-threading-in-tcl) requires that you do access to any particular instance of a Tcl interpreter from the thread that created that interpreter. (Tcl's implementation uses thread-specific data extensively.) You can fill those C arrays from another thread — usual C parallelism rules there — and then use [`Tcl_ThreadQueueEvent`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Notifier.htm) to tell the other thread that you've got something for it to do; the message you send is actually code+data.

```
struct DoneReadingIntoArraysEvent {
    Tcl_Event eventHeader;
    Tcl_Interp *interp;
    double *x, *y;
    int length;
}

struct DoneReadingIntoArraysEvent callback;
callback.eventHeader.proc = &MyCallbackFunc;
callback.interp = theInterpHandleInTheOtherThread;
callback.x = x;
callback.y = y;
callback.length = numberOfValuesInArray;
Tcl_ThreadQueueEvent(mainThreadId, &callback.eventHeader, TCL_QUEUE_TAIL);
```

Now, in `MyCallbackFunc` you cast the `Tcl_Event*` parameter back to a `struct DoneReadingIntoArraysEvent` (safe; it's the first member!) and retrieve the values you need to tell the interpreter about (and the interpreter in question).

For getting the values actually into Tcl, I'd *strongly* consider using a list `Tcl_Obj` containing a whole bunch of double `Tcl_Obj`s. This is a mechanism that wasn't available when BLT was first created, and it might have better performance than you're expecting.
Or if the number of values is large and you just need to pass them around and/or store them, send a big chunk of binary (the `binary scan` command will be able to pick bits out if needed).

Relevant APIs would be `Tcl_NewListObj`, `Tcl_NewDoubleObj` and `Tcl_NewByteArrayObj`.